# Unable to see autocomplete for Cocos2d classes in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocos2d-iphone, xcode6

I've create the project using SpriteBuilder like the documentation said, I've also create the MainScene swift class in Xcode and everything seems works fine. The problem it's that i can't see the Nodes classes and the autocompletion for those classes.

This is my Bridging-Header file:

```
#import "CCNode.h"
#import "CCNodeColor.h"
#import "CCLabelTTF.h"
#import "CCButton.h"
#import "CCLayoutBox.h"
```

in my init method on my MainScene if I'm doing something like this:
[image]

As you can see the autocomplete doesn't show me classes like CCNode or CCNodeColor.
Where it's the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*just another Xcode fail!*

here is a workaround:

import in your Bridging-Header cocos2d.h

```
#import <cocos2d.h>
```

now the trick :o)

drag cocos2d.h from subproject into your project where YOUR source files are!

```
libs->cocos2d-ios.xcodeproj->cocos2d->cocos2d.h
```

no need to copy

may be you need to restart xcode or wait a bit.